# JavaScript use object keys to create arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Hi I've an array of object

```
const carCode = "F1.1";
const arr = [
    {
        "id": 169138,
        "name": "Volkswagen",
        "flag": "add"
    },
    {
        "id": 173212,
        "name": "Skoda",
        "flag": "add"
    },
    {
        "id": 175555,
        "name": "Mercedes",
        "flag": "delete"
    }
]
```

Expected O/P

```
{
    "F1.1": {
        "add": [
            {
                "id": 169138,
                "name": "volkswagen"
            },
            {
                "id": 173212,
                "name": "skoda"
            }
        ],
        "delete": [
            {
                "id": 175555,
                "name": "mercedes"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm newbie in JS and really not sure how can we transform the above object to get the desired result.
I got the flag from  `const set = new Set(arr.map(a => a.flag));` I created object, but didn't actually quite got how do I uniquely loop the values and attach the array to "add" and delete.

```
const set = new Set(arr.map(a => a.flag));
console.log([...set])
```

Comment: What is that first code block representing? You have a label and then an array that's just...there.

Comment: @tadman basically grouping by `flag`

Comment: Use the technique described in the duplicate to group by `flag`, then add the result to a new property named `F1.1` on a new object.

Comment: It'd be nice if the array has a variable association instead of just being there. Is that what you mean by `arr`?